# TypeError: sequence item 4: expected str instance, list found

Tags: python

I converted the string to integer and after doing certain calculations and storing it in a different variable, I converted back to string using `str()` and store it in the list with other string and join them using `''.join()` but its showing as error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "solution.py", line 18, in <module>
print(''.join(tf))  

TypeError: sequence item 4: expected str instance, list found
```

```
import sys
time = input().strip().split(":")
y=0
if (time[2][2:]=='PM'):
    k=int(time[0])
    if(k!=12):
       y=k+12
else: 
   k=int(time[0])
   if(time[0]==12):
      y=0;
if k==0:
   tf=["00:",time[1],":",time[:2]]
else:
   tf=[str(y),":",time[1],":",time[:2]]
print(''.join(tf))
```

Comment: You're using `time[:2]`, did you mean `time[2]`? You're slicing the array into a smaller array instead of getting a single element.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that **user2896976** got it: **join** takes a list of strings; your last element, **time[:2]** is a list within that list.  You can't **join** a string to a list.

I changed both of those references (one each in the True & False branches of the **if**).  I gave it input `10:30:15PM` and got output `22:30:15PM`.  Note that this is incorrect: you need to remove the "PM" from that.

Here's my change to the last part of the code, complete with tracking **print**s.

```
print ("TRACE k=", k)
if k==0:
   tf=["00:",time[1],":",time[2]]
   print ("TRACE tf T=", tf)
else:
   tf=[str(y),":",time[1],":",time[2]]
   print ("TRACE tf F=", tf)
print("RESULT:", ''.join(tf))
```